Date/Time Format VBA Access Query
I am new to Access and I have a code here below that is supposed to insert the current month to a table through the current date I have in my pc subtracted with 1 hour:
strSQL = "INSERT INTO [mytable] ([monthColumn]) "
strSQL = strSQL & "VALUES ("
strSQL = strSQL & "#" & Format(Now - (1 / 24), "mmmm") & "#"
strSQL = strSQL & ");"

DoCmd.SetWarnings False
DoCmd.RunSQL (strSQL)
DoCmd.SetWarnings True

I also tried this:
strSQL = "INSERT INTO [mytable] ([monthColumn]) VALUES (#" & Format(Now - (1 / 24), "mmmm") & "#);"

DoCmd.SetWarnings False
DoCmd.RunSQL (strSQL)
DoCmd.SetWarnings True

For both codes, I am getting this error:

I only derived the codes above from a working code below:
strSQL = "INSERT INTO [mytable] ([monthColumn]) VALUES (#" & Now() & "#);"

What could be missing? Thanks in advance.

Use DateAdd() to subtract time https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dateadd-function

Also what data type is this field? It seems like it won’t accept “December” as a value which you’re supplying by formatting as “mmmm” https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/format-function-visual-basic-for-applications

@Marcucciboy2 datatype is General Date

@June7 ty. will use update for my other update queries. was just trying to test this query if it will work. I now changed my datatype to short text.

A column of 'Date' data type holds a valid date with its constituents: 'day', 'month' and 'year'.  A month name is not a valid date, it is just 'text'. You can't store just text (even if it is an abbreviation of a month name) in  a date column. Store it in a column with type: text.

Or store a full date like 12/1/2024 then date parts can easily be extracted with intrinsic functions as needed, including month name or number. Month names do not sort chronologically, need month number for that.

@June7 yes. ty. i will explore this on how to

It is rarely a good idea to store literals.
You could store the date minus 1 hour in a DateTime field:
strSQL = "INSERT INTO [mytable] ([dateColumn]) VALUES DateAdd('h', -1, Now())"
CurrentDb.Execute strSQL

And then - to display the month name - just apply the Format: mmm
Or, store the month value in an Integer field:
strSQL = "INSERT INTO [mytable] ([monthColumn]) VALUES Month(DateAdd('h', -1, Now()))"
CurrentDb.Execute strSQL

And then - when displaying the month - use the expression:
=MonthName([monthColumn],True)

